# Unity Client and Server

Tags: network-programming, unity-game-engine

In Unity4.
I'm making a network client and server.. Two different unity types.
The client is the actual game, the server is a separate plain server.

I don't quite understand what an RPC is. I understand that it is essentially a function called over the network, but how do I use it?

I have to instantiate the object new prefab.. Whenever I look at a tutorial it tells me to do this: transform.position

What is transform.position, isn't it my position?

How do I connect to the server then have my position updated? How do I get other people's position?

My idea was in the update of NetworkManager I would call an RPC to move the player to new position if it's not the same as the old one?

```
Network.Instantiate (PlayerController, transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);
```

transform.position?

PlayerController is the FirstPersonController put into a prefab and renamed..

What do I need to make on the server part of it? The server is basically just a connection between all the clients, do I even need the RPC function on the server?

When someone connects, how do I get it so the server tells everyone that someone connects and how do I send that person who just connected the positions of all the new players?

```
void Update () {
    Transform newPos = Network.player.transform;
    if (oldPos != newPos)
    networkView.RPC ("UpdatePosition", Network.player, 
}

public void OnPlayerConnected(NetworkPlayer player){
    Network.Instantiate (PlayerController, transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);
}

public void OnPlayerDisconnected(NetworkPlayer player){
    Network.RemoveRPCs (player);
    Network.DestroyPlayerObjects (player);
}
```

That is the client so far.. I need the UpdatePosition to update that single player's position on all screens..